# how to recalculate serial number in a html table after removing row by jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have following table layout:

```
<table border="1" id="staff">
  <tr><th>S/N</th><th>Company</th><th>Contact</th><th>Country</th></tr>
  <tr id="1"><td>1</td><td>Futter</td><td>Anders</td<td>Germany</td></tr>
  <tr id="2"><td>2</td><td>Berglunds</td><td>Christina</td<td>Sweden</td></tr>
  <tr id="5"><td>3</td><td>Centro</td><td>Francisco</td<td>Mexico</td></tr>
  <tr id="8"><td>4</td><td>Handel</td><td>Roland</td<td>Austria</td></tr>     
</table>
```

Now, after pressing delete button, a jquery function post the tr id to the processing php page, and after successful php & mysqli deleting operation, the processing php page send callback message to table page. The jquery function then remove the consequent row from the html table:

```
$("body").on("click",".del",function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   var table= 'staff';
   var id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id'); 
       $.post(url,
        {
         table: tbl,
         trid: id,
        },function(data){
          var callback_msg = data.return_msg;
          if(callback_msg=='delete'){
            $('#'+id).remove();
          }
       });
});
```

so, if an user wish to delete 3rd row with tr id 5, after deletion of that row, S/N column is remained unchanged like this:

```
<table border="1" id="staff">
  <tr><th>S/N</th><th>Company</th><th>Contact</th><th>Country</th></tr>
  <tr id="1"><td>1</td><td>Futter</td><td>Anders</td<td>Germany</td></tr>
  <tr id="2"><td>2</td><td>Berglunds</td><td>Christina</td<td>Sweden</td></tr>
  <tr id="8"><td>4</td><td>Handel</td><td>Roland</td<td>Austria</td></tr>     
</table>
```

You can see serial number column is now 1,2,4 (as serial number 3 is removed).

How can I include a function in my jquery code, so that after deletion it will re-order the serial number to 1,2,3 (i.e serial number of last row will become 3)?

[note: deletion may be in the middle row. so the .last() selector may not work in this case]

Comment: it is tr id (1,2,8), not the serial number. The S/N column is the serial number. Please see value of S/N number column is now 1,2,4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After deleting the row, just loop through its siblings updating their first cell:

```
var callback_msg = data.return_msg;
if(callback_msg=='delete'){
    var row = $(document.getElementById(id)); // Or continue to use the invalid ID selector: '#'+id
    var siblings = row.siblings();
    row.remove();
    siblings.each(function(index) {
        $(this).children('td').first().text(index + 1);
    });
}
```

**Live Example** *(I had to add a `.del` element to each row, I assume you're doing that somewhere...)*:

```js
$("body").on("click",".del",function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   var table= 'staff';
   var row = $(this).closest('tr');
   var id = row.attr("id");
   alert("Deleting id #" + id);
   setTimeout(function() { // Simulating ajax
       var siblings = row.siblings();
       row.remove();
       siblings.each(function(index) {
         $(this).children().first().text(index);
       });
   }, 100);
});
```

```css
.del {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" id="staff">
  <tr><th>S/N</th><th>Company</th><th>Contact</th><th>Country</th><th></th></tr>
  <tr id="1"><td>1</td><td>Futter</td><td>Anders</td><td>Germany</td><td class="del">X</td></tr>
  <tr id="2"><td>2</td><td>Berglunds</td><td>Christina</td><td>Sweden</td><td class="del">X</td></tr>
  <tr id="8"><td>3</td><td>Handel</td><td>Roland</td><td>Austria</td><td class="del">X</td></tr>
  <tr id="9"><td>4</td><td>JLR</td><td>Jag</td><td>UK</td><td class="del">X</td></tr>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

From the comments, you seem unsure where to put the above. Here it is in context:

```
$("body").on("click",".del",function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   var table= 'staff';
   var id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id'); 
       $.post(url,
        {
         table: tbl,
         trid: id,
        },function(data){
          var callback_msg = data.return_msg;                   //
          if(callback_msg=='delete'){                           //
            var row = $(document.getElementById(id));           // Changed
            var siblings = row.siblings();                      // code
            row.remove();                                       // is
            siblings.each(function(index) {                     // here
                $(this).children('td').first().text(index + 1); //
            });                                                 //
          }                                                     //
       });
});
```

Although actually, this would be more efficient and avoid selecting by `id` at all:

```
$("body").on("click",".del",function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   var table= 'staff';
   var row = $(this).closest('tr');                            // *
   var id = row.attr('id');                                    // *
       $.post(url,
        {
         table: tbl,
         trid: id,
        },function(data){
          var callback_msg = data.return_msg;                   // *
          if(callback_msg=='delete'){                           // *
            var siblings = row.siblings();                      // *
            row.remove();                                       // *
            siblings.each(function(index) {                     // *
                $(this).children('td').first().text(index + 1); // *
            });                                                 // *
          }                                                     // *
       });
});
```

---

Note about using `'#'+id` when `id` is a number: ID selectors starting with digits (like `#1`, `#42`, etc.) are **invalid**. jQuery supports them in isolation (e.g., `$("#1")` works but `$("#1 span")` does not) as a *by-product* of the fact that it optimizes them, using `getElementById` under the covers. That is undocumented behavior which, in theory, could change at any time. (In *fact*, if they changed it, I can't imagine how many sites they'd break. :-) ) I avoid relying on undocumented behavior, so I'd suggest `$(document.getElementById(id))` instead, which relies solely on *documented* behavior.

Comment: Your suggestion is correct and useful. But I have to send an id or whatever the name is (it may dbid instead of id) because based on this id or dbid, row from the mysql database will be deleted first. Then it will send callback data to the first page in order to remove the row from the html table. If I follow your suggestion, I have to get that id or dbid by selecting the tr using index and then .attr('dbid'), if use dbid instead of id.

Comment: @AbdullahMamun-Ur-Rashid: No, you still get the ID to send to the server the same way: From the `id` attribute.

Comment: So, It will be my great pleasure if you show me the full code according to your opinion,  how the row will be deleted from the database first.

Comment: I have removed my comment. $(this) selector is working even after removal of the row. But you have not shown in your code the post request to the processing page. Anyway thanks. I up voted your answer.

Comment: @AbdullahMamun-Ur-Rashid: You do the ajax request exactly as in your code! If you just take the code block at the beginning of the answer and put it where the equivalent block is in your code (in the ajax completion handler), that's all you need to do.

Comment: @AbdullahMamun-Ur-Rashid: I've added the code in context.

Comment: although it is slightly different than my topic, but related and requires a little change of your code. That's why I am not opening a separate topic/question. What about if I add a new row instead removing? It is recalculating the serial number for siblings except the newly added row. It is excluding the newly added row for increment the serial number and the serial number of next row is remain same as serial number of newly added row. How to change the code so that it can cover the both situation (Removing or adding)? Plz suggest here in this topic @T.J Crowder.

Comment: @AbdullahMamun-Ur-Rashid: When adding, first add the row, then do `theNewRow.siblings().addBack().each(...)` with the same `.each` code as above.

Comment: Do I have to define theNewRow or it will automatically identify the new row?

Comment: @AbdullahMamun-Ur-Rashid: `theNewRow` was my standin for whatever you have that refers to the new row.

Comment: what should be passed in closest() if i am working with DIVs instead of TABLE

Comment: @KhushbooGupta - It's a selector specifying the element to find ([docs](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)).

Comment: Its been 4 years..but still working awesome..upvoted (Y)